# Passing local variable by reference to a C++ thread

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reviewing the code of a junior colleague and encountered the following code.

```
void ActionGetId(boost::property_tree::ptree& callInfo);
void ActionPutId(boost::property_tree::ptree& callInfo);

void handler(int type, std::string data)
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree callInfo(data);
    if(type == 0)
    {
        _ioService.post(boost::bind(&ActionGetId, callInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        _ioService.post(boost::bind(&ActionPutId, callInfo);
    }
}
```

They are passing a local variable by reference and then exit the function. When those functions are finally called, the local variable may not exist. Yet, this program doesn't crash. How is this working?

Comment: _"Yet, this program doesn't crash. How is this working?"_ That it doesn't crash doesn't mean it works properly. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: `callinfo` gets copied inside boost bind.

Comment: Could you simplify the code so that it is clear what is being passed to a thread and how? Nobody knows what `_ioService.post` does.

Comment: An easy guess for any boost library user. It is io_service::post() function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`boost::bind` copies the arguments you give it and stores the copies in the function object it returns. When the function is called, it will not act on a reference to the local variable (which no longer exists), but on a reference to the copy (which is still valid).

If you actually wanted `boost::bind` or `std::bind` to use a reference to the variable (which you don't want here), you'd need to pass the variable to `bind` with `boost::ref(var)` or `std::ref(var)`.

Comment: Ah, ok. I always pass by shared_ptr or by value to bind functions. Didn't realise it handles references differently. Good to know. Thanks.